# Passing large string to Pipelinebuffer (C# and SSIS)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to load a large string (over 8000 characters) into a SQL Server database. (from a file)

I'm using `PipelineBuffer` to add a row and populate the output.

Using a script would return an error saying that it can't process more than 8000 character per field.

Using Text streamer will prevent me from adding a row as it convert the Text streamer to a blob component and it is marked as read only.

My work around was to alter the `BufferWarpper.cs` and load my data. Is there anyway to load the data without altering the `BufferWarpper.cs` (as it this script is generated automatically do not alter)

Comment: It sounds like you are asking whether you can load a string with more than 8000 characters into a data flow and have it... editable by the standard components? Am I tracking you here?

Comment: I just want to load it. I don't have to edit it. setting my output as string in Script Component will fail (max limit reached)

Comment: Then what is the challenge with setting the column type as DT_TEXT/DT_NTEXT? I mean, there can be a performance impact but that's how one gets large object types into a data flow which you then land as n/varchar(max) or the legacy LOB data types

Comment: The challenge is when using DT_TEXT or DT_NTEXT it is automatically (Unless I am missing something) converted to a Blob object (can not be set unless you alter the "unalterable" BufferWarpper.cs) something that I don't want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blob columns have a method called AddBlobData() for setting the value.  In the example below, Column1 is NText data type:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"<path to file>"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] columns = line.Split(',');
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                Output0Buffer.Column1.AddBlobData(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(columns[0]));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried it and it is working, I can set data into the blod, but when I pass the data to Sql Server, it only retrieve the first character, any suggestions?

Comment: What datatype is the output column set to and what is the datatype of the destination column in sql server?  Also, can you check what the value looks like in the data viewer before it gets into sql?

Comment: In Sql server it is set to be text, and in Data Viewer it just saying <long text>

Comment: I think you might need to change the encoding to Ascii: `Output0Buffer.Column1.AddBlobData(Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes(columns[0]));`

Comment: Well, it did work thank you, but since my string has french characters, they are not properly displayed in the data base

Comment: Oh geez, no worries. Change that back to Unicode, make the database column nvarchar(max) and change the output column in ssis to ntext. Then everything will support international character sets